# Can I increase the bounty amount over time?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, bounty

Can people be able to increase the amount of bounty after they put the bounty on a question? If there isn't, I think it should be because when a question still stays unanswered after you put a bounty on it, you should be able to add more bounty to get the question answered more quickly. Isn't the objective of bounties inducing people to answer the questions? All in all, there should be a command to add more bounty to a question that has already been offered a bounty. Because, it would be time saving since you have to wait a week to offer more bounty on the question with this system.

Comment: So what you're basically proposing is a way for people to "feed the meter". Add extra rep to the bounty and this, in turn, lets the bounty stay open longer? Say, 7 days from the time you last added rep to the bounty

Comment: @Jim Yes, that is what I am proposing basically. It not only makes the bounty stay up longer but also adds more bounty to help the question gets answered more quickly.

Comment: makes sense to me. But I think the minimum amount of rep to add to the bounty would have to increase each time, otherwise people could game the system. Instead of a +300 bounty, they could successively add +50 to the bounty for six weeks. Or they could just add +50 to the bounty every week to keep a question hot forever and never award a bounty

Comment: But you should make this a feature request

Comment: @Jim Yes there should be regulations for stopping system abuse. And thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: This would be a network wide feature, so it should be discussed on the mother meta. I see that Jim found [just such a discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/203902/262980).

Comment: @dmckee I wasn't aware of that discussion. I am sorry. However, why this kind of system is not used and accepted since it seems like community liked the idea in that discussion?

Comment: @Starior It's no problem, it's just that opening a discussion like this on the physics meta isn't going to get very far: it'll have to be discussed on the mother meta anyway. As for why it hasn't been implemented, we have to assume that the team has given it a low priority because (1) +27/-4 is not a particularly strong vote; (2) it is not preventing users for performing core site features; and (3) they may want to let it stew awhile to so people have a chance to think up the abusive corner cases. The good news is that it has not been marked [status-declined] or even [status-deferred].

Comment: @dmckee Okay so since there is a discussion for this topic on mother meta I think this thread should be closed. Am I right?

Comment: I don't know if we have a policy on that.

Comment: What you should consider doing is posting an answer in support on the mother meta thread. That should revive the question

Answer (score 2):

It seems we must have violated causality (only logical explanation) because almost a year ago someone posted a [suspiciously similar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/203902/262980) feature request on the mother meta that includes the stuff we talked about.

It doesn't look like any mods really looked it over thoroughly and I didn't see many persuasive arguments against it. So with that in mind, I'd be for allowing people to feed-the-meter as long as protective measures like an increasing minimum rep payment is implemented. Perhaps also, the any rep from the bounty that is 7 days old should be treated like 7 day old bounties in the current system to prevent users from building up questions with 5000 rep bounties, which could effectively bypass the rep cap to let them do all sorts of things (get their friends to trusted status in a week, for example). Or there should be a maximum rep cap on bounties that's, say, 3X the current max rep.

But these are just ideas, I'm for it until I hear a good argument against it. The details can be worked out by people more motivated than I.